# Get data from 3 tables for toxi tagging system

Tags: php, mysql

Here i have 3 tables with the following structure.

Post:

post_id  | Post_name 
---------+----------
1               |   Test Post
2                |    India

Tag:

tag_id   |  tag_name
---------+------------
1                |      java
2                |      php

Tag_map:

tag_map contain only foreign key from post and tag tables.

post_id    |   tag_id
-----------+------------
1                    |        1
1                    |        2
2                    |        1
2                    |        2

I want to get the data from the particular post_id which is given by the user.

Can any one help me for this??? I"m a very beginer to php..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so from the given example what is the desired output ?

Comment: It's not about PHP it's more SQL problem. You just need to select with jointure.

Comment: Have you done anything? You are asking for a SQL statement…

Comment: i'm very new to php. sorry if i ask anythink wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to JOIN the data something as below and this will return data in multiple rows when the post has multiple tags in the `tag_map`

```
select 
p.post_id ,
p.Post_name,
t.tag_name 
from tag_map tm 
join Post p on p.post_id = tm.post_id
join Tag t on t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
where p.post_id = 'some id';
```

For getting data in a single row per each post and all the tags as comma separation you will need to use `group_concat()` as

```
select 
p.post_id ,
p.Post_name,
group_concat(t.tag_name) as tag_name
from tag_map tm 
join Post p on p.post_id = tm.post_id
join Tag t on t.tag_id = tm.tag_id
where p.post_id = 'some id'
group by p.post_id
;
```